# Is "All Related Objects" field of an object's Feed Tracking options available in metadata?

Tags: chatter, metadata-api, metadata, package, chatter-feed-tracking

After enabling "Publisher Actions" for Chatter, you can tick a checkbox called "All Related Objects" for a specific object in Setup > Customize > Chatter > Feed Tracking.  This will turn on the functionality where a Chatter post is created on the object whenever any child object is created.

However, I can't find where this "All Related Objects" field is stored in metadata?  I don't see it in the metadata for a custom object, which is where I would expect it to be.

Is this field available somewhere else in metadata?    If so, is it packageable?

Thanks,

Artie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of chatter settings are not available in Metadata API yet, including this option.

Unfortunately I could not find any reference of this setting in the metadata api documentation.

So this will will have to be a manual step, post deployment.

Comment: Thanks Gunish.  Feed tracking for individual objects *is* in the metadata API, but I, too, could not find this option either.  Thanks.